# Identical linq for different index

Tags: c#, linq

I am parsing excel data and need to create object based on StartDate-EndDate difference.

Is there a better way to have only one linq perform this task and return two different result sets ? Only difference in both linq is just the variable on which its applied.

```
private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, List<DataPoint>>>[] ParseData(ExcelFile file, Dictionary<string, string>[] ConfigMap)
{

    // Extract the information from the excel file
    var excelData = file.GetWorksheetData(sheet: 0, rowStart: 2);

    var monthlyRows = excelData.Rows.Where(r => (DateTime.FromOADate((double)r[EndDateCol]) - DateTime.FromOADate((double)r[StartDateCol])).Days > 1);
    var dailyRows = excelData.Rows.Where(r => (DateTime.FromOADate((double)r[EndDateCol]) - DateTime.FromOADate((double)r[StartDateCol])).Days == 1);

    var monthlyData = monthlyRows.Where(r => r[KeyCol] != null && ConfigMap[0].ContainsKey((string)r[KeyCol]))
                                   .GroupBy(r => (string)r[KeyCol])
                                   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                                                 g => g.GroupBy(r => DateTime.FromOADate((double)r[DateCol]))
                                                       .ToDictionary(c => c.Key,
                                                                     c => c.Select(r => new DataPoint(DateTime.FromOADate((double)r[StartDateCol]), new Decimal((double)r[PriceCol])))
                                                                           .ToList()));

    var dailyData = dailyRows.Where(r => r[KeyCol] != null && ConfigMap[1].ContainsKey((string)r[KeyCol]))
                                  .GroupBy(r => (string)r[KeyCol])
                                  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                                                g => g.GroupBy(r => DateTime.FromOADate((double)r[DateCol]))
                                                      .ToDictionary(c => c.Key,
                                                                    c => c.Select(r => new DataPoint(DateTime.FromOADate((double)r[StartDateCol]), new Decimal((double)r[PriceCol])))
                                                                          .ToList()));

    return new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, List<DataPoint>>>[] { monthlyData, dailyData };
}
```

Comment: I love `var` with a passion, but in this specific context it's not clear what type `monthlyRows` and `dailyRows` are.

Comment: where enumerable ExcelDataRows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `monthlyRows` and `dailyRows` are both `IEnumerable<ExcelDataRow>`, a first step could be to *extract a method* (assuming return type here, I only skimmed through your code):

```
private Dictionary<DateTime, List<DataPoint>> GetDataDictionary(IEnumerable<ExcelDataRow> data)
{
    var result = data.Where(r => r[KeyCol] != null && ConfigMap[0].ContainsKey((string)r[KeyCol]))
                                   .GroupBy(r => (string)r[KeyCol])
                                   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                                                 g => g.GroupBy(r => DateTime.FromOADate((double)r[DateCol]))
                                                       .ToDictionary(c => c.Key,
                                                                     c => c.Select(r => new DataPoint(DateTime.FromOADate((double)r[StartDateCol]), new Decimal((double)r[PriceCol])))
                                                                           .ToList()));    
    return result;
}
```

Your `ParseData` method's body could then look like this:

```
    // Extract the information from the excel file
    var excelData = file.GetWorksheetData(sheet: 0, rowStart: 2);

    var monthlyRows = excelData.Rows.Where(r => (DateTime.FromOADate((double)r[EndDateCol]) - DateTime.FromOADate((double)r[StartDateCol])).Days > 1);
    var monthlyData = GetDataDictionary(monthlyRows);

    var dailyRows = excelData.Rows.Where(r => (DateTime.FromOADate((double)r[EndDateCol]) - DateTime.FromOADate((double)r[StartDateCol])).Days == 1);
    var dailyData = GetDataDictionary(dailyRows);

    return new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, List<DataPoint>>>[] { monthlyData, dailyData };
```

---

That solves *one* issue.

Next step would be to break down the LINQ query and make the code self-explanatory as far as *why* you need to have a dictionary of dictionaries of lists.. and then make that simpler.

Comment: That dict of dict is required with some other reasons. Was wondering if I can slice the data based on Date difference and apply the linq to prepare result all in one linq only and get two different results for different conditions. Guess its too much to ask for :)

Comment: @buffer_overflow make sure you check out our [help/on-topic] to see what CR is all about - it's possible you get answers with alternative implementations, but the answers you should be expecting are answers that identify weak spots in your coding style and in your implementation. But yes, it's possible. Take a look at what type that the `Where()` method is expecting - that's the type you could take as a parameter to the extracted method if you wanted to supply a condition.

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering. As I haven't seen linq implementation which works on two different conditions in same statement and returns two different results say a list or array of size = number of conditions.

Comment: Why have the `result` variable at all? Instead, you could simply `return data.Where(…`.

Comment: @svick true, ..I systematically assign those to something, just to I have a chance to break and inspect when debugging, there's no other reason - actually now that I think of it, that's not even a good reason... I should stop doing that?